# Dynamicaly add layout in layout?

Tags: android, layout

I have a layout and i need to insert into in some kind of blocks with text - like comments date, name, text. Is there a way to use it like this

```
 for (int r=0; r<10;r++) {
      TextView t1=(TextView) findviewbyid(R.id.text1);
      t1="BlaBla";
      mainlayout.add(commentLayout);
 }
```

So i get something like listview but without adapter and etc.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name"
    android:id="@+id/comm_name"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Date"
    android:id="@+id/comm_date"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/comm_text" />
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, do you have a problem with it?

Answer (score 5):

you can do it, but the way you are doing it will throw an exception, because `findViewById` returns always the same object, and after the first iteration `t1` has already a parent. You should create a new instance of the `TextView` programmatically, at every iteration.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding views dynamically in linear layout which is inside scroll view.

Try this code.I know it is not exact solution.But,Hope it gives you some idea.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ScrollView scrollview;
    LinearLayout  linearLayout;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    static int i;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        scrollview = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView view = new TextView(MainActivity.this);             
                view.setText(++i+" view");
                linearLayout.addView(view, layoutParams); 
            }

        });

}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Following approach

**Looping to add dynamically Views to Linear Layout**

```
TextView textView1, textView2;
LinearLayout completeLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        textView1 = new TextView(Activity.this);
        textView2 = new TextView(Activity.this);
        String name1 = "xyz";
        String name2 = "abc"
        completeLinearLayout.addView(textView1);
        completeLinearLayout.addView(textView2);
        setTextViewParam(textView1, name1);
        setTextViewParam(textView2, name2);

    }
```

**Method to set TextView Parameters Dynamically**

```
private void setTextViewParam(TextView tv, String text) {

    LayoutParams textLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textLayoutParams.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 0);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    tv.setText(text);
    tv.setTextSize(13);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tv.setLayoutParams(textLayoutParams);

}
```

Now you can customize the views according to need and container as well.
Happy Coding!!

Comment: For any problem ask me :)

Comment: Oky.. Please post your layout with markup and tell me which values I need to set Up. I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: here how will you change the textview object dynamically as it always returns the same object?

Answer (score -1):

So, this code works exactlay as i need.
Is there anything wrong with it??

```
public class InflateView extends Activity {

LinearLayout lLayout;
TextView t,f;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);

    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
            RelativeLayout tv = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.text, null);
            lLayout.addView(tv);
            t = (TextView) tv.findViewById(R.id.ttt);
            t.setText("aaaaaaa" + i)  ;
            f = (TextView) tv.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            f.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    }
}}
```